# Set state based on localStorage in Angular, NGRX

Tags: angular, local-storage, state, ngrx

When I log in I set a token in `localStorage`, now I want to set state based on it, like in React, is it possible in `ngrx` ?

I used local-storage-ngrx package but can't configure it in correct way, state keeps reseting although I set `rehydrate` to true.

Comment: Yes, it is completely possible unless you terminate your application an relaunch it.